# Is it a requirement that a Kalman Filter uses a state space system model?

Tags: kalman-filter

I have a problem to solve where I need to know the temperature inside a device and I have a very poor sensor from which to measure it. This problem has led me to a Kalman filtering method.

The temperature in the device changes very slowly; collecting enough system identification data is time consuming so I decided to create a model using the finite difference method.

Every text I have read recommends a state space model of the system. Is there any reason I shouldn't use some completely separate modelling technique? My thoughts are that a state space model will certainly be linear and time invariant whereas my finite difference model won't be.

Comment: Part of the problem is that I cannot fully calibrate the sensor, so I was planning to calibrate the sensor from a model in the first instance, and then rely on the sensor instead of the model in the long run. I considered that I could adjust the observation matrix in the Kalman filter to facilitate this but I'm not sure.

Comment: The Kalman Filter is an estimation method for a state space model. If you can use the Kalman Filter to estimate the mean and variance-covariance matrix of some state you imply a corresponding state-space model (and you can write it down from the matrices you use in the KF).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have finite difference, you can also try hidden Markov Chain.

I am not clear about your idea that a state space model will certainly be linear. We always define a state space model with the following format:

$Y_t = X_t + e_t$, $e_t \sim N(0, 1)$

$X_t = X_{t-1} + a_t$, $a_t \sim N(0, 1)$

but another format:

$Y_t = X_t + J_t\cdot e_t$, $e_t \sim N(0, 1)$

$X_t = X_{t-1} + K_t\cdot a_t$, $a_t \sim N(0, 1)$

where $J_t$ and $K_t$ are under the Markov Chain assumption, for example, $J_t$ could be 1 or 100, so it is non-linear. Well, not sure if this is what do you mean by 'a state space model will certainly be linear and time invariant'.

Comment: I probably misunderstood the state space representation, I saw some algebraic manipulation of a 1st order difference equation into state space representation so my confusion probable stemmed from there!

Comment: @Hefaestion Actually, a lot of models can be written in the format of state space model, for example, autoregressive model. Based on the case, if you have finite discrete difference, then I will recommend hidden Markov Chain.

Comment: How would I create the hidden Markov Chain model? Would I have to train a Markov model from inputs and outputs of the finite difference heat equation model?

Comment: @Hefaestion Not really understand your data, but if you have a sample from temperature inside a device and sensor data, then you can design the difference and then apply the hidden markov chain on them. But there is only my understanding based on your question.